# Why my Flatlist are not rerendering when states changes?

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-toolkit

I have a list of users. I want to set one person to mute. In my redux store its updated fine. But its not rerender although I use extraData. But Why?

UserList/Bottomsheet

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Pressable, Image, Dimensions, Animated } from 'react-native';
import BottomSheet, { BottomSheetFlatList } from '@gorhom/bottom-sheet';
import { chatMock, chatMockFlat } from '../../../utils/mockChat';
import { AntDesign, Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { useSelector, useDispatch, shallowEqual } from 'react-redux';
import { handleSetMuteOn } from '../../../redux/slice/chat/chatSlice';

const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');

function propsEqual(prevName, nextName) {
  return prevName.isMuted === nextName.isMuted;
}

const Item = React.memo(({ name, date, image, id, text, modal, fixed, muted, onPressMute }) => {
    console.log('RERENDERs');
  return (
    <Pressable delayLongPress={100} onLongPress={() => modal(id)}  style={s.chatItem}>

      <View style={s.viewLeftImage}>
        <Pressable onPress={onPressMute} style={s.imagePress}>
          <Image source={{uri: image}} style={s.profile_image} resizeMode='contain' />
          <View style={s.onlineStatus}></View>
        </Pressable>
      </View>

      <View style={s.viewMidText}>
        <View style={s.viewHeaderText}>
          <View style={s.nameContainer}>
            <Text style={s.name}>{name}</Text>
            { fixed === 1 && (
            <View style={s.pinContainer}>
             <AntDesign name="pushpino" size={12} color="#bbb" />
            </View> )
            }
            { muted === 1 && (
            <View style={s.pinContainer}>
             <Ionicons name="volume-mute-sharp" size={12} color="#bbb" />
            </View> )
            }
          </View>
          <Text style={s.date}>{date}</Text>
        </View>
        <Text style={s.text}>{text}</Text>
      </View>

    </Pressable>
  )
}, propsEqual);

const userState = state => state.chatSlice.userList;

const BottomSheetChat = ({  Modal }) => {
  const userList = useSelector(userState);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [refresh, setRefresh] = React.useState(false);

  const handleMuteChat = React.useCallback(() => {
    setRefresh(!refresh);
    dispatch(handleSetMuteOn());
  }, [dispatch]);

  const bottomSheetRef = React.useRef(null);

  // variables
  const snapPoints = React.useMemo(() => ['25%', '100%'], []);

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <Item 
      name={item.name} 
      date={item.date} 
      image={item.image} 
      id={item.id}
      text={item.text} 
      fixed={item.isFixed} 
      modal={(e) => Modal(e)}
      muted={item.isMuted}
      onPressMute={handleMuteChat}
    />
  )

  return (
    <View style={s.container}>
      <BottomSheet
        ref={bottomSheetRef}
        index={1}
        style={s.sheetContainer}
        snapPoints={snapPoints}
        handleStyle={{borderTopLeftRadius: 16, borderTopRightRadius: 16,}}
      >
        <BottomSheetFlatList
          data={userList}
          keyExtractor={i => i.id}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          extraData={refresh}
        >

        </BottomSheetFlatList>
      </BottomSheet>
    </View>
  )
};
```

Slice:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { chatMockFlat } from "../../../utils/mockChat";

const chatSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'chatSlice',
  initialState: {
    unreadChats: 0,
    headerSearchChats: '',
    currentUserID: null,
    modalOpen: false,
    userList: chatMockFlat
  },
  reducers: {
    handleSetMuteOn(state, action) {
      state.userList = state.userList.map(el => {
        if(state.currentUserID === el.id) {
          return {
            ...el,
            isMuted: 1
          }
        } else {
          return {
            ...el
          }
        }
      });
    },
    handleSetMuteOff(state, action) {
      state.userList = state.userList.map(el => {
        if(state.currentUserID === el.id) {
          return {
            ...el,
            isMuted: 0
          }
        } else {
          return {
            ...el
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
});

export const { handleSetMuteOff, handleSetMuteOn } = chatSlice.actions;

export default chatSlice.reducer;
```

Updates Correct (The array of the user is changed from Mute 0 to Mute 1, so its a new state.

I use refresh i n extra data.

So why its not working ?

€:

Output prev/next prop:

```
START
Prevname: 0
Nextname: 0
START
Prevname: 1
Nextname: 1
START
Prevname: 0
Nextname: 0
START
Prevname: 0
Nextname: 0
START
Prevname: 0
Nextname: 0
START
Prevname: 0
Nextname: 0
START
Prevname: 0
Nextname: 0
START
Prevname: 1 // THAT ARE THE NEW CHANGES (SUCCESS) IT WAS Zero
Nextname: 1 // THAT ARE THE NEW CHANGES (SUCCESS) IT WAS Zero
START
Prevname: 0
Nextname: 0
START
Prevname: 0
Nextname: 0
START
Prevname: 0
Nextname: 0
START
Prevname: 0
Nextname: 0
```

Comment: Should the index prop of BottomSheet be set to 1? Also, did you try without React memo?

Comment: Yes it should be 1, I removed propsEqual at Item Memo and it works. but why ? PropsEqual stay to there

Comment: Did you mean to write `muted` instead of `isMuted`? If it's undefined then it will always stay memod.

Comment: its not undefined i destructed muted like this muted={item.isMuted}

Comment: @windowsill is correct. The `propsEqual` function would receive `prevProps` and `nextProps`. There is no `isMuted` prop rather a `muted` prop. I don't see the destructuring. Did you not paste that code here?

Comment: @AndyFaizan ok you are right, but its not rerender again. What I am doing wrong ? if I remove propsEqual its work, but propsEqual should be there

Comment: Have you logged prevProps.muted and nextProps.muted, can you show the output? Also I don't think there should be a propEqual function, when props change that lead to a new UI the component should render. Also I don't think this is right `handleMuteChat = React.useCallback(..., [dispatch])`, it needs another dependency `refresh` otherwise it will always set it to true. Plus if you're using extra data to render the flatlist, that will happen before the redux state update happens. Instead, it should rely on the reference to userList updating.

Comment: @windowsill First, I have updated my post and you can see the output. Second I removed refresh and added userList to extradata that solves the problem before updating the redux store. But it still not working

Comment: Did you try `function propsEqual(prevProps, nextProps) { return prevProps.muted === nextProps.muted; }` like everyone is suggesting?  Your `refresh` prop isn't going to work for the reasons that @windowsill explained.  But this `refresh` is a roundabout around your actual problem which is the `propsEqual` function.